# Getting 'unable to find valid certification path to requested target' in the integration test

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to use Wiremock to mock two different APIs responses in an integration test. To be clearer, I have a Spring Boot microservice that consumes other 2 APIs (bible-api.com and jsonplaceholder.typicode.com), afterwards I join the 2 responses and send it back to the client. It's just a POC to learn how to use [Wiremock with multiple domains](https://wiremock.org/docs/multi-domain-mocking/). So, I need Wiremock to step in and respond in place of bible-api.com and jsonplaceholder.typicode.com. My integration test is like this:

```
package me.brunosantana.wiremock.integration;

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.WireMockServer;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.http.JvmProxyConfigurer;
import jakarta.annotation.Resource;
import me.brunosantana.wiremock.util.FileReaderUtil;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock.*;
import static com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.core.WireMockConfiguration.options;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class IntegrationTest {

    @Resource
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    /*@Test
    public void testApiIntegrationTest() {
        given()
                .when()
                .get("http://localhost:8080/albums/1/bible/john/3/16")
                .then()
                .log().all()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body("album.albumId", is(1))
                .body("album.photos[0].title", equalTo("accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt"))
                .body("bible.reference", equalTo("John 3:16"));
    }*/

    @Test
    public void testApi() throws Exception {
        //SETUP
        FileReaderUtil fileReaderUtil = new FileReaderUtil();
        String body1 = fileReaderUtil.read("jsonplaceholder-response.json");
        String body2 = fileReaderUtil.read("bible-response.json");

        WireMockServer wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(options()
                .enableBrowserProxying(true)
                .dynamicPort()
                .dynamicHttpsPort()
                //.httpsPort(443)
                .trustAllProxyTargets(true)
        );
        wireMockServer.start();

        JvmProxyConfigurer.configureFor(wireMockServer);

        wireMockServer.stubFor(get("/albums/1/photos")
                //.withScheme("https")
                .withHost(WireMock.equalTo("jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"))
                .withPort(443)
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withBody(body1)));

        wireMockServer.stubFor(get(urlPathMatching(".+\s.+"))
                //.withScheme("https")
                .withHost(WireMock.equalTo("bible-api.com"))
                .withPort(443)
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                        .withBody(body2)));

        //TEST
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("http://localhost:8080/albums/1/bible/john/3/16")
                        .content("{}")
                        .headers(new HttpHeaders()))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is2xxSuccessful())
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andReturn();

        //TEAR DOWN
        wireMockServer.stop();
        JvmProxyConfigurer.restorePrevious();
    }

}
```

But when I run the code I get this exception:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I tried to use MockMvc and Rest Assured to make the request, but always get the same exception. The problem seems to be that I consume both external APIs using https and the JVM needs the certificates inside the keystore/cacert. I already tried to import the certificates using many ways, for example the process for the bible website certificate would be:

1 - download the certificate as .pem

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect bible-api.com:443 -servername bible-api.com  </dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > bible-api.com.pem
```

2 - convert it to .cer

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in bible-api.com.pem -outform DER -out bible-api.com.cer
```

3- import the .cer in the keystore

```
keytool -import -alias bible -keystore cacerts -file bible-api.com.cer
```

I also tried for example this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# cacerts.sh
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect $1:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM > /tmp/$1.pem
/some/path/here/corretto-17.0.5/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -file /tmp/$1.pem -alias $1 -keystore /some/path/here/corretto-17.0.5/lib/security/cacerts
rm /tmp/$1.pem
```

In order to run it:

```
./cacerts.sh bible-api.com
```

Of course I repeated the process for the other domain (jsonplaceholder.typicode.com). Nothing worked! I'm pretty sure I'm importing the certificates in the cacerts related to the JDK I'm using to run the test.

If you want to run my code, it's here in [this repo on GitHub](https://github.com/brunosantanati/integration-tests/tree/main/wiremock).

Does anybody have any idea why I'm still getting the error?

Thank you!

Comment: I was able to get a way around it not using https for the tests, I created an application.properties specific for tests where I override the URLs to be used in the tests, each of which uses http instead of https (see [here](https://github.com/brunosantanati/integration-tests/blob/main/wiremock/src/test/resources/application-profile1.properties)).